# Closed form for integral arising from marginalisation of Gaussians

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, closed-form

If one has a probability distribution $p(x,y)$, then
$$p(y)=\int dx\ p(x,y)$$
In the conceptually very simple case that $x$ is drawn from a unit Gaussian and then acts as the variance of another Gaussian from which $y$ is drawn one has an integral of the form ($C$ is some constant):
$$p(y)=\int dx\ p(x,y)=\int dx\ p(y|x)p(x) =C\int_{\Bbb R}dx\ \frac{e^{-y^2/x^2}}{|x|}e^{-x^2}$$
Which is completely beyond what I am capable of.

> Does a closed form for this integral exist?

(Remark: $p(y\mid 0)$ should correspond to $\delta_{y,0}$, but I have ignored this in all my considerations with the belief that it is irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
p(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~\frac{e^{-y^2/x^2 + x^2}}{|x|} = 2 \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~\frac{e^{-y^2/x^2 + x^2}}{x}
$$

Make the change $ u = x^2/y$, such that ${\rm d}u = 2x{\rm d}x/y$ and

$$
p(y) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}x~x\frac{e^{-y(y/x^2 + x^2/y)}}{x^2} = \int_0^{+\infty}{\rm d}u~\frac{e^{-y(1/u + u)}}{u}
$$

Now, I'm going to make the change $u = e^t$, with this

$$
p(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~ \exp[-y(e^{t} + e^{-t})] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~ \exp[-2y\cosh(t)] = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~ \exp[-2y\cosh(t)]
$$

On a little side note, the modified [Bessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1_.2C_K.CE.B1) function of the second kind $K_{\alpha}(x)$ can defined as

$$
K_\alpha(x) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t~ \exp[-x\cosh(t)]\cosh(\alpha t)
$$

Therefore

$$
p(y) = 2K_0(2y) ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ y > 0
$$

Comment: That was a typo on my behalf, the correct expression uses $|x|$. $p(y)$ being constant zero is incompatible with its character of a probability distribution.

Comment: @s.harp I see, in this case the answer is $p(y) = 2K_0(2y)$

Comment: Very nice! I expect I will be dealing with such integrals in the future when I want to propagate certain probability distributions (ie [exponential families](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)) in the above way. Do you think these kind of things are doable? Personally I had thought that the $e^{1/x^2+x^2}/x$ kind of term from this easy example would have already been extremely hard.

Comment: @s.harp That definitely depends on the PDF, but in my experience, more often than not it is possible to find a trick for solving these integrals